# How do different applications running in the same process share user id and app certificate

Tags: android

It is about different applications running in the same process. 
I have read that they share a user id and are signed with the same certificate.

My questions are:

1. User ID is defined [here](http://www.linfo.org/uid.html) as :

   > A user ID (UID) is a unique positive
   >       integer assigned by a Unix-like operating system to each user. Each
   >       user is identified to the system by its UID, and user names are
   >       generally used only as an interface for humans.

Now since users are applications installed on the linux system, user
        id is the unique identifier of the application in the linux system.

**So how can two applications share the same user id. Moreover, what if two applications developed by different developers ever ever
        share the same user id?**

1. I have read [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) that:

> The Android system requires that all installed applications be
>   digitally signed with a certificate whose private key is held by the
>   application's developer. The Android system uses the certificate as a
>   means of identifying the author of an application and establishing
>   trust relationships between applications.
>   
>   **So how can different applications, say developed by different developers, be signed with the same certificate?**

**3. Can somebody give me an example in which components of different
        applications are running in the same process?**

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there something wrong with my question? Nobody is answering it =(

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.pluralsight.example.ShareApp1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ShareApp1Activity extends Activity {
    private static final String         LOG_TAG = "ShareApp1Activity";
    private static final String         SHARE_APP2_PKG_NAME = "com.pluralsight.example.ShareApp2";
    private static final String         DATA_DIR_FILES_DIR = "/files";
    private static final String         SHARE_APP2_DATA_FILE = "data.txt";

    private PackageManager              mPM;
    private TextView                    mApp2Path;
    private TextView                    mApp2Data;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //  Get the package manager, we will use it to find the app info
        //  for our other package.
        mPM = getPackageManager();

        //  Get the UI components we need to set as part of our activity.
        //  This is going to include a text field showing where the other
        //  app is installed as well as a graphic component found in the
        //  other package.
        mApp2Path = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.share2_install_path);
        mApp2Data = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.data_file);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        String                  path = null;
        String                  data = null;

        super.onStart();

        //  Use the PackageManager to retrieve the details for our other
        //  package.
        try {
            ApplicationInfo ai =
                mPM.getApplicationInfo(SHARE_APP2_PKG_NAME,
                                       PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            path = ai.dataDir;
            path += DATA_DIR_FILES_DIR;
            File inFile = new File(path, SHARE_APP2_DATA_FILE);
            FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(inFile);
            int len = (int)inFile.length();
            if (len == 0) {
                in.close();
                throw new IOException();
            }

            byte[] dataBytes = new byte[len];
            in.read(dataBytes, 0, len);
            in.close();
            data = new String(dataBytes);
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            path = getString(R.string.app2_not_found);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {
            data = getString(R.string.no_data_file);
        } catch (IOException e3) {
            data = getString(R.string.no_data);
        }

        mApp2Path.setText(path);
        mApp2Data.setText(data);
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.pluralsight.example.ShareApp1"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0"
          android:sharedUserId="pluralsight.example.shareId">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="ShareApp1Activity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>

package com.pluralsight.example.ShareApp2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ShareApp2Activity extends Activity {
    private static final String        DATA_FILE_NAME = "data.txt";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        FileOutputStream out = null;

        super.onStart();

        //  Write out a simple data field.
        String dataStr = getString(R.string.data);
        try {
            out = openFileOutput(DATA_FILE_NAME, 0);
            out.write(dataStr.getBytes(), 0, dataStr.length());
            out.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.nofile), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.ioerr), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            finish();
            if (out != null) {
                try {
                    out.close();
                } catch (IOException e2) {
                    //  ignore
                }
            }

            return;
        }

        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.now_load_1), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        finish();
    }
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.pluralsight.example.ShareApp2"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0"
          android:sharedUserId="pluralsight.example.shareId">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"/>
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="ShareApp2Activity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```